# Url input stream not showing

Tags: java, android, json, url, stream

I'm trying to get input stream from URL to be displayed on TextView when clicked on a certain button in my android app. I used someone else's code from internet tutorial step by step but it doesn't work for me. The TextView is always empty even though it should already show the text. I would deeply appreciate any help.

```
public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String data="";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/j5f6b");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while(line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
               data = data + line;
            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        CurrencyConvert.text.setText(this.data);

    }
}
```

```
public class CurrencyConvert extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button click;
    public  static TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_currency_convert);

        click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetchText);

       // data.setText("");

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fetchData process = new fetchData();
                process.execute();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to add the `INTERNET` permission in your manifest? Are you getting any stack traces printed in your logs from those `catch` blocks?

Comment: This is the line I added, doesn't work anyway. 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

With this logs: 2019-09-08 14:27:51.877 18441-20028/com.example.kalkulator24072019 D/MyTag: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to somevaliddomain.com not permitted

Comment: `somevaliddomain.com`? Did you redact the domain you show in the question? Or are you actually using a different URL?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare TextView as static varible of Activity class. Instead pass activity instance to fetchData class constructor (btw. class names should start with uppercase)

```
public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    CurrencyConvert activity;

    public FetchData(CurrencyConvert activity) {
        this.activity= activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // do background stuff...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        activity.setTextInTextView(this.data);
    }
```

In Your Activity declare public method for setting text:

```
    public class CurrencyConvert extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button click;
        TextView text;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_currency_convert);

            click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetchText);

            data.setText("");

            click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    fetchData process = new fetchData(this);
                    process.execute();
                }
            });
    }

    void setTextInTextView(String data) {
        text.setText(data);
    }
}
```